# C# and JavaScript - Escaping Single Quote Character

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, escaping

I have an XML file storing a string like the following:

```
Error: The form's name field was left empty!
```

Now, this message in the XML file is used in various locations.  For instance, it is sometimes bound to an aspx control and sometimes displayed in a JavaScript alert.

In order to escape the single quote character, I modified the message as follows:

```
Error: The form\'s name field was left empty!
```

When the message is shown in a JavaScript alert, it is displayed as it should with the single quote escaped.  However, when it is bound to an aspx control, it is displayed as is.

I tried modifying the message as follows:

```
Error: The form&#39;s name field was left empty!
```

and

```
Error: The form&lsquo;s name field was left empty!
```

With these two cases, the message displays as it should when bound to an asp control.  However, when passed to a JavaScript alert, I get the ") expected" error in IE8.

How can I get this to work for both aspx controls and JavaScript alerts please?  I have already wasted a lot of time on it.  Thank you so much.

N.B. I am using a very old version of the .NET Framework, specifically 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just store your messages verbatim and then let each client handle the special character. So, store as `Error: The form's name field was left empty!` and then within each language add a step that checks for special characters and escapes them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Isn't there a specific sequence that works for both cases?  For example, &quot; for double quotes works for both cases.

Comment: This approach gives you maximum flexibility as not every scenario will be handled in the same way in each language. It is best for your data to be separated from your coding language.